# How to make a listview one after another? - Swift

Tags: swift, listview, swiftui

I am trying to make a list view one after another and this keeps happening. Is there a way to take out one of the back buttons and only show one? Does swift have a sort of feature that removes the back button as it does for hidden navigation view? This is how it looks:
[image]

He is the code I used for the original list:

```
@ViewBuilder func jsonSelector(using id: Int) -> some View {
         switch id {
            case 1:
         SCaliView()
            case 2:
         BAView()
         case 3:
            DesertView()
         case 4:
            NCoastView()
         case 5:
            CCoastView()
         case 6:
            SVView()
         case 7:
            SNView()

         default:
            ContentView()
         }
    }
    
    // MARK: - BODY
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
                    VStack() {
                            
                            NavigationView {
                                Group {
                                    List {
                                        
                                        
                                        ForEach(regions) { regions in
                                            NavigationLink(destination: jsonSelector(using: regions.id)) {
                                           RegionButtonView(regions: regions)
                                            }
                                        }
                                    } //: LIST
                                } //: GROUP
                                .navigationBarTitle("Region", displayMode: .large)
                                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                            } //: NAVIGATION
                        
                        Spacer()
                    } //: VSTACK
                } //: ZSTACK
                .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .top)
                .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .bottom)
```

And here is the code I used for the second list:

```
ZStack {
            NavigationView {
                Group {
                    List {
                        ForEach(sclocations) { sclocations in
                            NavigationLink(destination: SCDetalView(sclocations: sclocations)) {
                                SCButtonView(sclocations: sclocations)
                            }
                        }
                    } //: LIST
                    .navigationBarTitle("Region", displayMode: .large)
                    .navigationBarHidden(true)
                }
            } //: NAVIGATION
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .top)
        .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .bottom)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need NavigationView in your first view

Take out NavigationView from your detail view and it’ll work fine and remove the duplicated back button.

```
ZStack {
            Group {
                List {
                    ForEach(sclocations) { sclocations in
                        NavigationLink(destination: SCDetalView(sclocations: sclocations)) {
                            SCButtonView(sclocations: sclocations)
                        }
                    }
                } //: LIST
                .navigationBarTitle("Region", displayMode: .large)
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
            }
    }
    .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .top)
    .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .bottom)
```

Comment: That's the thing, I don't have a navigation view in the detail view. It's set up as if I have a list that leads to another list and then the detail view. And if I remove the navigation view from the second list, It doesn't let me go back to the first list, if that makes sense. @rlong405

Comment: You do have a NavigationView in the second list, which shouldn’t be there. The `navigationBarHidden` is hiding that second one, I guess. I also don’t see a need for the ZStack, VStack, Group, or Spacer in either view… removing those my clear up some of your issues.

Comment: Sorry yes, when I said detail view, I actually meant second list. So you’ve removed the navigation View from your second list? And now back button isn’t there or doesn’t work? I guess you’ve also removed your navigation bar hidden code on your second list too after you removed Navigation View from second view? Do you have your code hosted anywhere where I could have a look please?